# my vector only takes in 10 digits how can i make it more?

Tags: c++, vector, integer, iostream, cmath

I've been playing with a bit of code, trying some stuff, and I wanted to make a program that could take in any amount (or at least 100) digits of numbers and then add them up, but ti my dismay, it only shows 10 for some reason, and I'm not sure why.  I've tried a lot of stuff, which hasn't helped.

I've tried changing the size of the vector, making the int into long long int,  or trying something from the internet, but nothing helped.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<long long int> number;
    long long int av;
    cin >> av;
    for (int i = 0; i != 342; i++) {
        double fool = pow(10, i);
        int lol = int(fool);
        long long kik = (av / lol);
        int c = kik % 10;
        if (c > 0)
            number.push_back(c);
    }
    int hah = 0;
    for (int j = number.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (number[j] > 0) {
            cout << number[j] << endl;
            hah = hah + number[j];
        }
    }
    cout << hah << endl;
}
```

Comment: `pow(10, i);` gets big. Real big. Way past the ability of `int` to hold pretty quickly.

Comment: To eliminate the `pow` function, try this:  `uint32_t fool = 1u; for (/*...*/) { /*...*/ fool = fool * 10u; }`.  This is a running power method.  More efficient and better accuracy with integral types.  Most processors can perform the multiplication in one instruction whereas calling `pow()` requires a minimum of 4 instructions.

Comment: Any program that calls `pow()` with two integers is fundamentally flawed. You might be surprised to learn that `pow(10, 2)` is not, exactly, 100.

Comment: You may want to invest in a Big Number Library.  Look up [numeric limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) for your compiler.

Comment: I think you need to explain the algorithm to us very clearly so we understand what you are trying to do. Whatever it is that you want done, this code doesn't do it, so we need to know exactly what you want done so we know what needs fixing. Plus a lot of the time simply trying to explain what you're doing shakes the solution loose.

Comment: The basics of why you get few numbers, say you plug in 42 for `av`. By iteration 3 `lol` is 100 and `(av / lol)` -> `(42 / 100)` -> `0`. That means `kik % 10;` is 0 and `c > 0` is never again true. Until `lol` starts overflowing, and by then your guess is as good as mine what'll happen. We're soundly mired in Undefined Behaviour land.

Comment: Tactical note: If you want to sum up numbers, don't store them. Set the sum to 0. Then every time you compute a new number you want summed, add it to the sum. All you need is the current sum and whatever scratch variables you need to compute the number you're thinking of summing. Never store anything you don't need to.

Comment: A `long long int` is only guaranteed (for an implementation that conforms with the standard) able to represent (about) 18 decimal digits.  Using `pow()` (a floating point function) when working with integral values is bad practice, due to loss of precision.    No standard numeric types in C++ have arbitrary range (e.g. able to represent an arbitrarily large number of digits) and floating point also has limited precision. (Also, most beginners, when they ask for big integers, often don't actually need that - there are often alternatives that they have overlooked).

Answer (score 2):

You want to read in a very large number, and then add up its constituent digits. I think you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. There is no type that is going to hold an int with hundreds of digits. That's a *big* number: the largest number a 64-bit unsigned int can store is `18446744073709551615` which has twenty digits.

Instead use a string, then iterate over its digits, convert them to *very small* ints, and sum them.

E.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string in;
    std::getline(std::cin, in);

    unsigned int sum = 0;

    for (auto c : in) {
        if (!std::isdigit(c)) {
            std::cerr << "Non-digit char encountered." << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        sum += c - '0';
    }

    std::cout << "Sum is " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```